# Standard notation to indicate certain distributions

Tags: distributions, prior, notation, cauchy-distribution

On a figure that I wish to annotate to indicate what prior distributions were used in an analysis, I need a shorter way of indicating a $\text{Cauchy}(0, \sigma)$ distribution and saving just 3 or 4 letters would make an enormous difference to the font size I can use (and thus, to the readability of the figure).

Obviously, for many distributions such as the normal distribution ($N(\mu, \sigma^2)$), uniform distribution ($U(a,b)$), Student's t-distribution with $\nu$ degrees of freedom ($t_\nu(\mu, \sigma)$), exponential distribution ($\text{Exp}(\lambda)$) or negative binomial ($\text{NegBin}(\mu, \kappa)$) it is common to use a short abbrevation in notation to indicate the distribution. E.g. $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$ instead of $X \sim \text{Normal}(\mu, \sigma)$.

Are you aware of a good list of such convential notations that are frequently used and in particular of a notation that is common for the Cauchy distribution? I did not manage to find any examples. If not, are the obvious clashes with other conventions, if I were to use $\text{C}(0, \sigma)$ or $\text{Ca}(0, \sigma)$?

Comment: As long as the notation is self contained, well explained, and not obviously "taken," then you should be fine. When I see $C()$ in this context, I think of the family of continuous functions, but it is doubtful that there will be a conflict in the context of your paper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go with your proposal, but be sure to explain it somewhere in the paper.  In this context there should be little risk of confusion.  I very much doubt that there is some official list of standard notation.